# How to do casting in AsAsyncOperation?

Tags: asynchronous, windows-runtime, async-await

I am having a crash course on WinRT IAsyncOperation, async, await. I am trying to wrap Task with IAsyncOperation but fail to come up with an easy way to do the casting.

```
public interface IInfo{}
public class InfoList : IInfo{}

public class Parser {
    private async Task<InfoList> ParseList() {
        var returnList = new InfoList();

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Task<string> htmlTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://stackoverflow.com");

        string html = await htmlTask;
        // parsing logic...
        return returnList;
    }

    public IAsyncOperation<IInfo> Parse()
    {
        return AsyncInfo.Run(_ =>
            Task.Run<IInfo>(async () =>
            {
                var returnList = await ParseList();
                return returnList;
            })
        );
        // I have tried following but causes InvalidCastException
        //return (IAsyncOperation<IInfo>)ParseList().AsAsyncOperation<InfoList>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public IAsyncOperation<IInfo> Parse()
{
    return AsyncInfo.Run(async _ => (IInfo) await ParseList());
}
```

or

```
public IAsyncOperation<IInfo> Parse()
{
    return AsyncInfo.Run(_ => ParseList().ContinueWith(t => (IInfo)t.Result));
}
```

Comment: maxim pg. You are awesome.

Answer (score 2):

The `IAsyncOperation<>` type is not covariant, meaning you can't cast an `IAsyncOperation<InfoList>` to an `IAsyncOperation<IInfo>`.

Try having your `ParseList` method return a `Task<IInfo>` instead.

Comment: Thanks for introducing the word "covariant" to me.  
  
  
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx  
  
"Variance for generic type parameters in interfaces and delegates (since C# 4.0)"  
  
The conclusion is WinRT adds pain to programmers...

Comment: But I want to stick with Task<InfoList> ParseList() because I think return type should be more descriptive. Actually, I am afraid that the extra Task.Run<IInfo> async added by me will add too much delay to my application.